# Content-Disposition: inline for PDF file in ASP.Net not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, mozilla, content-disposition

I am trying to return PDF file to browser with header `Content-Dispostion:inline` right after I am creating this file.
Viewers of browser have problem to open it.

File is not corrupted. If I put into browser, viewer shows file correctly.
But I want create file and check users rights for file at one request.

Here is my headers and response set up:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline");
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("filename", $"objednavka-{OrderId}.pdf");
HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(File.ReadAllBytes(filePath));
HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

Firefox have error at file *viewer.js*, message undefined, line 1453.

Response in Network in debugger of Firefox is *200 OK*.

But message in browser is connection lost (interupted).

Comment: Have you tried adding `content-length` header? `HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-length", File.ReadAllBytes(filePath).Length);`

Comment: Nit: there is no "filename" response header field in HTTP.

Answer (score 4):

both advices help. Thank you guys.
this is how looks correct answer:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", $"inline; filename=\"objednavka-{ OrderId}.pdf\"");
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-length", File.ReadAllBytes(filePath).Length.ToString());
HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(File.ReadAllBytes(filePath));
HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```